# How to export image with MySQL data by PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

In my MySQL table (label_entry) there are three columns namely:

1. RBO
2. Brand
3. location (image link storing) for identifying a product item.

My image folder location is "../label_image/". I want to export MySQL data with image to Excel. I can export the MySQL data to excel but image is not exporting.

If I define one image with full path information then the image is exporting, but I want to export all the image based on item and it should display per rows wise corresponding its item.

I am new to PHPExcel and  don't know where I need to make correction. Any advice will help me to understand here.

````
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();<br/>
 $query = "SELECT * FROM label_entry";<br/>
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());<br/>
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();<br/>
 $rowCount = 2;<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:C1')->getFont()->setBold(true);<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:C1')->getFont()->setSize(16);<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:C1')->getFont()->setItalic(true);<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(30);<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(30);<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Trim Database');<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','RBO');<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1','BRAND');<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1','IMAGE');<br/>
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['RBO']);<br/>
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['Brand']);<br/>
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();<br/>
$objDrawing->setName('test_img');<br/>
$objDrawing->setDescription('test_img');<br/>
$objDrawing->setPath('../label_image/2PK.jpg');<br/>
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('C1'); <br/>                     
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(5); <br/>
$objDrawing->setOffsetY(5); <br/>               
$objDrawing->setWidth(105); <br/>
$objDrawing->setHeight(45); <br/>
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());<br/>
  $rowCount++;<br/>
}
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-   officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');<br/>
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="survey.xlsx"');<br/>
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');<br/>
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');<br/>
 $objWriter->save('php://output');<br/>```
````

Comment: Can you obtain the full path of the uploads directory and concatenate the image name?

Comment: you have to specify full path of the image name.

Comment: Using the `../` in `setPath` will not work as expected. As mentioned in the comments above you will need to supply the full path to the image.

Comment: What's with all the `<br/>` at the end of each line?